# Nested function calls from the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple `<li>` elements. When I click to one of this, data from the chosen `<li>` should populate fields of form below. But my problem is when I click on the list of `<li>` tags it works from the second click.

```
<div class='js-delivery-addresses' id='delivery_addresses'>
  <ul>
   <li> one </li>
   <li> two </li>
   <li> three </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Js code:

```
events: {
  "click .js-delivery-addresses": "chosenAddress"
}

chosenAddress: function() {
  ...some code here;

  $('#delivery_addresses li').unbind().on('click', function() {
    ...other code that works from second click;
  })
}
```

I expect it will work from the first click.

Comment: Could you show a full working example of the problem. The JS logic appears to be in the initialisation settings of another library, plus it implies you're nesting handlers which isn't a good idea.

Comment: try using class and remove unbind
$('.js-delivery-addresses li').on('click', function() {
    ...other code that works from second click;
  })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this not much simpler ?

```js
$(document).on("click","#delivery_addresses ul li",function(){
  alert($(this).val() + " = " + $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='js-delivery-addresses' id='delivery_addresses'>
  <ul>
   <li> one </li>
   <li> two </li>
   <li> three </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach works fine for me, but I still don't understand why code from nested function didn't work, because of nesting handlers, or I missed something?